# ListBox item padding in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, html, css, listbox

My CSS says:

```
option { padding: 6px; }
```

This works as expected in Firefox - that is, it puts padding around all items in a list box. However IE ignores the style rule. Is it possible to achieve the same result in IE?

I'm using ASP.NET and did consider scrapping the list box and using a ListView but the functionality isn't the same - I need users to be able to select and double-click on elements and scroll with the arrow keys in an intuitive way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change very much in select boxes, at best the color and background of the option text
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx